# jQuery mobile search input in header (overtop/overlay of header) with fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I am currently working on a jQuery mobile project. In the header I have an icon for panel on left, center is a title and right is a search icon.

The search icon currently reveals a search input, which works great. The Input is revealed above header and everything else is pushed down.

My question is how can I adjust this so the search input reveals within the header (like an overlay) as opposed to above the header. 
Along with a close button (X) to return to default header?

```
<body>


<div data-role="page" data-theme='d'>

    <div data-display="push" data-role="panel" data-theme="c" id=
    "sidebar">
        <ul data-icon="false" data-inset="false" data-role="listview">

            <li>
                <a data-ajax="false" href="index.html"><i class=
                'fa fa-home fa-fw'></i>Home</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div >
 <form data-ajax="false" action="search.html" data-theme="b" id="searchform" name="searchform">

 <input data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" data-role="none" id=
            "" name="q" placeholder="Search..." type=
            "text">
        </form>
    </div>


    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="true" data-theme='b'>

         <a data-role="none" href='#sidebar'><img alt="sidebar" id="header-menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.png"></a>

   <h1 class="header-title">Hvac Techpedia</h1>

     <a data-role="none" href='#' id="a-search"><img alt="search" id="header-search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png"></a>
```

Here is a fiddle of the CSS, HTML and JS. Click the search bar on the top right.

http://jsfiddle.net/xstrikax/cj6nc8xa/4/

Been tinkering around but cant seem to figure it out. Adding `data-positon="fixed"` to header makes the bar (search input) appear below header.

This is somewhat of an example of what I am looking to do:

http://www.style.com/magazine

Using JQM 1.4.5 & Jquery 1.11.1.

Any help or suggestions would be great! Thanks!!!!

Comment: I can't seem to get the close button to work on mobile devices. Works in all browsers. Any suggestions for alternate "close" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by putting the search form within the header and setting its position to 'absolute'. Then use the top-margin to animate it into view.

```
<div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="true" data-theme='b'>         
    <form data-ajax="false" action="search.html" data-theme="b" id="searchform" name="searchform">
        <input data-clear-btn="true" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" data-role="none" id="" name="q" placeholder="Search..." type="text" />&nbsp;<a id="closeSearch" href="#" class="ui-btn"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </form>
    <a data-role="none" href='#sidebar'><img alt="sidebar" id="header-menu-icon" src="images/menu-icon.png" /></a>
    <h1 class="header-title">test</h1>
    <a data-role="none" href='#' id="a-search"><img alt="search" id="header-search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png" /></a>
</div>
```

```css
#searchform {
     position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -moz-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -ms-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -o-transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    transition: all 350ms cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.665, 0.165, 0.130, 0.715);
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 44px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -44px;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchform.moved {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cj6nc8xa/8/)**

You can also simplify your code quite a bit.  jQuery mobile provides and event called **[vclick](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/)** that handles both clicks and touches. Instead of jQuery's document.ready, use the jQM pagecreate event, and rather than saving the state of the search bar, you can use the **[toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)** method:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $('#a-search, #closeSearch').on('vclick', function (event) {
        $('#searchform').toggleClass('moved');
    });    
});
```

Note: I have bound the same handler to both the search button and the close button.

> Updated **[FIDDLE-2](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/cj6nc8xa/10/)**

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks for the vclick heads up! This thought me a lot!

Comment: This works however it does not work very well on mobile devices. Once you click to open search it opens then immediately closes. Seems to be a double fire issue or delay. Is there another alternative for better function on mobile devices? Perhaps delay/halt taps during Css animation reveal?

Comment: have you tried adding e.preventDefault() or return false; on the button click event?

Comment: Not using a button, using an image. I believe that may be the cause. Where would I add preventdefault or return false?

Comment: @JASONFOREST, perhaps you can add some console.log() statements to see if it is getting triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

Had some mobile issue's. Added return false; to the code. Works much better on mobile devices. stopPropagation(); and prevent default; work good too.